# Why are visited links purple even with CSS color?

Tags: html, css

How I can fix shown in this [animation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8K7T0.gif)? I'm referring to the purple text. I think reason is transition, but I don't know how to fix that. It looks like that in Opera and Chrome. Internet Explorer looks normal. What I can do?

```css
.navitext {
  text-decoration: none;
  block: inline-block;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-filter: opacity
}

.navitext:hover {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.navitext:after {
  content: '';
  height: 2px;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: RGBA(255, 255, 255, 0);
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  bottom: -7px;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

.navitext:hover:after {
  background-color: RGBA(9, 255, 109, 0.7);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.bignav {
  color: black !important;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: right;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 2px;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  position: relative;
  transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
  background: RGBA(9, 255, 109, 0.7);
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: background 1s ease-in-out, color 1s ease-in-out;
  border: 3px solid RGBA(9, 255, 109, 1);
}

.bignav:hover {
  background: RGBA(9, 255, 109, 0);
  color: white !important;
}
```

```html
<a class="bignav" href="index.html"> Test test</a>
<a class="navitext" href="index.html"> Status</a>
<a class="navitext" href="index.html"> Ranking</a>
<a class="navitext" href="index.html"> Contact</a>
<a class="navitext" href="index.html"> Discussion</a>
```

[image]

Comment: That animation shows a "flash of unstyled content" (FAUC). How and where are you loading your CSS?

Comment: You're missing a closing braces on the `.navitext:hover` and `.navitext:hover:after` blocks. You also have an invalid rule: `block:inline-block;`

Comment: I use external css

Comment: I don't see the problem in a [Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qt82dcLu/).

Comment: I copied the code from this fiddle demo and still the same, any other ideas to fix that?

Comment: only in code on site

Comment: I'm looking for solve from 2 hours, and find only PHP solution.

Comment: why don't you want to correct the missings `}` ? is it a taboo ?

Comment: done :O and im still looking

Comment: I start thinking this problem come from elsewhere, what say your browser inspector ?

Comment: All html 5 websites defaults print vsisted links in purple it can be changed by what @Jacob Lockwood has done

Answer (score 1):

Use `a:visited`, or in your case, `.navitext:visited`:

```css
.navitext, .navitext:visited {
  ...
  color: white; /* or whatever */
}
```

Hope this is what you're looking for!